# React error .map() is not a function after updating API data

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary

I am currently working on a project where my react app connects to my own API. I've run into a problem that I can't seem to overcome. When I try to update my data I get an error saying map is not a function.

this is my vehicleOverview.js script this is supposed to show a list of all my available data which works fine until a I update a data element.

```
export class VehicleOverview extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state= {
        vehicles: [],
    }
    getAll().then((response) => {
        console.log(response.message);
  
        this.setState({
          vehicles: response.message,
        });
  
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
render(){
    return(
        <div >
        <h2>Vehicle List</h2>
        <ul >
        {    
          this.state.vehicles.map((vehicle, i) => {
             return(
            <Vehicle key={`vehicle-${i}`} {...vehicle} />);
          })     
        }
        </ul>
        </div>

    );
}
}
export default VehicleOverview;
```

I am not sure what is going wrong because I am pretty sure vehicles is an array. Tell me if I need to provide more code to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

I noticed two things here:

1. Using `this.setState` in constructor is not recommended, because component is yet to be rendered.
2. Always do api calls from componentDidMount - For the reasons mentioned in this [article](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/)

Also, just in case, add a condition before looping through vehicles.

```
import React from 'react';

export class VehicleOverview extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vehicles: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getAll().then((response) => {
      console.log(response.message);
      this.setState({
        vehicles: response.message
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h2>Vehicle List</h2>
        <ul>
          {this.state.vehicles && this.state.vehicles.map((vehicle, i) => (<Vehicle key={`vehicle-${i}`} {...vehicle} />))}
        </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
export default VehicleOverview;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I've read the article that you've provided and it makes sense. So I now used componentDidMount but it is still giving me the same error. Could it maybe be that I also need to implement componentdidmount to my script where I edit my data because it al goes wrong after I update data

Comment: No, componentDidMount should be defined only once, it is a lifecycle method, can you tell me the error it is showing?

Comment: error => TypeError: this.state.vehicles.map is not a function

Comment: I think when I update my data. the data is indeed not an array anymore. I'm just not sure why it doesn't format as an array after I update it

Comment: Do you mean `response.message` is not an array?

Comment: yes I think that what's causing the problem. After updating some data the response message isn't an array anymore but I can't find the reason why

Answer (score 0):

.map() function will work only for Arrays data.
check what typeof response you are getting.